# loadUrl(url, extraHeaders) not working in cordova android

Tags: android, cordova

I need to pass a header while loading a URL. Here, while loading, a popup comes asking to open the page using any webTool(whatever installed). I had chrome as a web browser in my device.

I am using the below piece of code:

```
Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
extraHeaders.put("CustHeader", "abc");
String url = "http://www.google.co.uk";
cwv.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any error on LogCat?

Comment: No errors. It is opening a popup to load the url in web browser(chrome) as it does, whenever we access any links. When i change the statement from loadurl(url, extraHeaders) to loadurl(url). It works fine and the page gets loaded on WebView.